# What are the numbers beside Amazon EC2 types for?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When looking to select an EC2 instance there are for example T2, M4... I understand they are all under the General purpose section, but do the numbers carry any significance?

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a multiplier. Seems like it'd make more sense to not care what they're called, but rather the actual specs.

Comment: Just like the T2 instances they are burstable and should be used only for on-demand work. Looks like the c4.8xl has 36 CPU credits/hr. If you run a single virtual CPU at 100% for 1 minute that will cost you a credit. Burstable instances will not recharge or use credits if the instance is running at 20% CPU load. Less will regenerate the credits and more than 20% will pull the credits. One last thing, if your instance is running under 20% load you will gain credits that last up to 24hrs. It's kind of complicated so try to size your instance based on the type of load it will have.

Comment: @EatatJoes: If you check the image that I posted on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46145928/1017797), I'm fairly sure that the missing header from the posters question is **vCPUs**. If you look at the [C4-Class in the Instance Types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#c4), it's specifically listed as having 32 vCPUs, and the description of vCPUs is "Each vCPU is a hyperthread of an Intel Xeon core except for T2 and m3.medium."

Comment: Not sure why people are down voting my question. Should I just delete this question. If it's such a stupid question then I wish people would answer it.

Comment: @JamieStarke I guess the question was banaler than I assumed and I just wanted it to be more ;)

Comment: thanks for your comment, I got  the answer, so I'll delete it.

Comment: Instead of deleting the question, why not improve the question based on your understanding now and how the question would have been better written?

Comment: @dellyjm: Which number ended up being the answer in this? We could improve the question and then it could get upvotes to compensate.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly which of the number you're asking about here.

If you're asking about the significance of the numbers in `t2`, `m4`, `c3`, `c4`, `f1` the number signifies the generation for each of these. the **M-series** are general purpose, where as **C-series** are Compute optimized, **T-series** are the burstable instances, **F-Series** have Field Programmable Arrays, and the number in these is which generation of a particular series each of these is based on. Newer generations generally have higher specs than older generations, and are also usually cheaper as they've become more optimized.

For anyone else that's curious, I believe this is the missing header from the posters image, taken from the "Choose an Instance Type" section of the Launch New Instance process:

[image: Description of Instance Types when launching a new instance]

The third column in your screenshot is the number of virtual CPUs each one gets. Think of this as how many cores your instance gets access to.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks very much. Too bad I'm deleting this question because of the downvotes.